# Is there an easy way to go from binary to ACSII like charCodeAt goes from text to ASCII?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a variable of

```
joinMsg = "0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0";
```

I made it from an array

```
putMsg = [ "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0" ]
joinMsg = putMsg.join();
```

My goal now is to convert this to the ASCII number, (which would be "f").  I'm trying to basically take a binary number and go back to ASCII then text.  I originally got this number by user charCodeAt to go from f to ASCII to binary.

Is there a simple way of converting back to text from a binary string?

I've tried praseInt like this...

```
var joinMsg = putMsg.join();
console.log(joinMsg);
var back = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(joinMsg,2));
console.log(back);
```

But back prints as a blank space, when I would expect it to print as 'f'

Added the answer given and then I added ("") to my join and it works!  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can go from a decimal number to a character with `String.fromCharCode` and from a binary number to a decimal integer with `parseInt` using the base `2`.

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt('01100110', 2)); //f
```

Comment: I tried the parseInt method and couldn't get it to work.  Does parseInt work on arrays?  Because my array print looks like '0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0 not '01100110'

Comment: I tried adding that - but it just printed a blank space

Comment: `var chr = String.fromCharCode(parseInt([ "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0" ].reduce((p,c) => p+c),2));`

Comment: I figured it out.  Just needed to add ("") to join and it removed the comma's